# Mod popup menu is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed

On the mobile site, the post "mod" popup menu is broken and adding a notice gives a 404.

I have a screenshot if needed.

Comment: I pinged our dev about this. He's looking into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in a build rolling out shortly, also post notices which were never added to mobile will now show up.